# Run code after all Tasks of ThreadPoolExecuter are completed

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method in which I create a some files using ThreadPoolExecuter, and later zip the files created.

```
private void createAndZip(){
    // Some Code
    ThreadPoolExecutor executer = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    for(String str : someStringList){
        // This piece of code creates files and drops to certain location.
        executer.execute(new MyRunnable());
    }
    executer.shutdown();
    // Code to Zip the files created above.
}
```

Now my piece of code to create zip files runs even before all files are created, so not all files are zipped.

Please help. I tried Sleep, but can't gaurantee how much time the files creation will take.

Comment: you could use countdown latch of five threads or number of tasks and await in main thread and countdown latch in each thread at end of task so after countdownlatch reaches 0 it will proceed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to invoke [`awaitTermination`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) on the executor object, in order to wait for the executor to finish shutting down.

Comment: And don't forget to check the return value

Answer (score 1):

I used a CountDownLatch to solve the problem. Here is sample code.

```
private void createAndZip() throws Exception{
    CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(someStringList.size());
    // Some Code
    ThreadPoolExecutor executer = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    for(String str : someStringList){
        // This piece of code creates files and drops to certain location.
        executer.execute(new MyRunnable(latch));
    }
    executer.shutdown();


    // Code to Zip the files created above.
    try {
        latch.await();
    } catch (InterruptedException exception) {
        throw new GIException(exception);
    }

    //Code here.
}

public class MyRunnable implements Runnable{
    CountDownLatch latch = null;

    MyRunnable(CountDownLatch latch){
        this.latch = latch;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            // Some Logic
            latch.countDown();
            } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code block you are narrowing the return of `Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5)`.  One option you have is to use the `ExecutorService` it returns.  This class already has facilities that avoid having to re-implement synchronization code such as latches. For example:

**Using Futures**

```
private void createAndZip(ExecutorService executor) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    // Some Code
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // For a number of reasons ExecutorService should be constructed outside
    // ExecutorService executer = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    List<Future<?>> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : list){
        // This piece of code creates files and drops to certain location.
        futures.add(executer.submit(new MyRunnable()));
    }
    // async work
    for (Future<?> future : futures) {
        future.get(); // blocks
    }

    // Code to Zip the files created above.
}
```

There are some advantages here:

- Error management: when executing the the background if you use another technique you have to arrange for errors to be delivered from the background thread to your master thread. Here the future takes care of this.  If your worker throws then the exception will back it back to your controlling thread.
- Keeping few threadpools in your code.  The reason to pool threads in the first place is to make the startup costs smaller.  If you have any significant sized program you wouldn't want to create and destroy threadpools whenever you wanted to perform an operation in parallel.

With Java8 Lambda this the loops can be written in a more compact way.

**Fork/Join**

Perhaps better suited to your task, particularly if you are going to process a tree of files is the [Fork/Join framework](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html).  Here you could roll the processing and the zipping into a collection of tasks that are submitted to the fork-join pool. That's neat because you can get a Future for the whole zip file allowing you to produce the entire zip off your main thread. Something similar to your design using fork/join might be:

```
static class PrepareFile extends RecursiveTask<Void> {

    private String filePath;

    PrepareFile(String filePath) {
        this.filePath = filePath;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void compute() {
        try {
            System.out.println(filePath);
            Thread.sleep(1009L);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return null; // void
    }
}

static class ZipTask extends RecursiveTask<String>
{

    private List<String> files;

    ZipTask(List<String> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }

    @Override
    protected String compute() {
        List<PrepareFile> prepareTasks = new ArrayList<>();
        for(String file : files) {
            PrepareFile fileTask = new PrepareFile(file);
            prepareTasks.add(fileTask);
            fileTask.fork();
        }
        for(PrepareFile task : prepareTasks) {
            task.join(); // can collect results here
        }
        System.out.println("Zipping");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Done task");
        return "filename.zip";
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool();
    List<String> toProcess = Arrays.asList("a","b");
    String filename = pool.invoke(new ZipTask(toProcess));
    System.out.println("Zipped " + filename);
}
```

This is an illustration you'd want to change a few things, like the the return types of the tasks and how the tasks are invoked perhaps.

**On awaitTermination**

It is possible to use the `awaitTermination` method after calling shutdown to wait for all processes to terminate. However this may not be so desirable in longer running services or programs where thread-pools may be shared between operations.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use `Future` objects here. Instead of calling `execute()` on the executor use `submit()` method. This should give you a `Future` object for each task you are submitting to the executor. Once you submit all tasks just loop over the list of futures you got and call `get()` on each. This is a blocking call and it waits until the corresponding task finishes.

Here the advantage is that you can retrieve any exception thrown from your task and then decide whether to zip the files or not.

Please refer this code -

```
private void createAndZip() throws Exception {
    // Some Code
    ThreadPoolExecutor executer = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    // collect all futures
    List<Future> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String str : someStringList){
        // This piece of code creates files and drops to certain location.
        futures.add(executer.submit(new MyRunnable()));
    }
    // wait for all tasks to finish
    try {
        for (Future future : futures) {
            future.get();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (e instanceof ExecutionException) {
            throw e;
        }
    } finally {
        executer.shutdown();
    }
    // Code to Zip the files created above.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void createAndZip() throws Exception{

    // Some Code
    ThreadPoolExecutor executer = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

    for(String str : someStringList){
        // This piece of code creates files and drops to certain location.
        executer.execute(new MyRunnable());
    }
    executer.shutdown();

    while (true) {
            boolean result_ = threadPoolExecutor.awaitTermination(TimeUnit.DAYS, 1);

            if(result_)
                break;
        }
    // Code to Zip the files created above.

    //Code here.
}
```

Comment: `while (foo) { break; }` makes no sense. It's literally equivalent to running `foo;` directly.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Can you please check the logic now

Comment: You could have just said `while (!foo) {}`. ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young I dint understand whats wrong in my approach

Comment: The new approach? It's just more verbose, that's all. (I've already explained what's wrong with the old approach.)